# How to get days in between two dates in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two dates, one is `assign_date` (date assigned) and the other one is `complt_date` (date completed). I have to get the number of days in between the two dates.

```
DATE ASSIGNED : 04-27-2012
DATE COMPLETED: 04-27-2012
THUS DAYS     : 0

NOT COMPLETED (AS OF 03-13-2013)
DATE ASSIGNED : 04-20-2012
DATE COMPLETED:
THUS DAYS     : 327
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at the query level, this could be more easier.

For MySQL database there is a function called DATEDIFF:-

```
ex:-  SELECT DATEDIFF(complt_date,assign_date) AS DiffDate
```